# How do I write a python script designed to analyse different XML schemas and convert XML files?

Tags: python, xml, xsd

I work a lot with a certain type of XML documents. Every few months a new schema for this XML document is released. Often a new schema will add or remove fields from the XML documents.

Currently I have to convert at least some of my XML documents from the old version to the new version. I do this by hand, but obviously that is not ideal.

I am relatively decent at writing Python scripts. However, I have very little experience with working with XML using Python.

I was wondering how difficult it would be to write a generic python script that analysed the new and old schema for these XML documents, identified the changes (which fields were removed and which ones were added), and converted old document versions to new version.

If this is possible/not too difficult for someone with somewhere between beginner and intermediate Python skills, would someone direct where I should look to get started?

I just read the XML chapter for "Dive into Python." It seems like the lxml library is the one that I would be looking to use? Is it very powerful when working with schemas?

Where should I go from here?

Comment: Start with ElementTree in the standard library.

Comment: I am afraid it is very difficult - or even impossible, unless there are some kind of rules/restrictions in the possible schema changes. If you have a schema with a `foo` attribute, and then a new version of the schema where this attribute has been renamed `bar1` and there is also a new attribute `bar2` - comparing the schemas what you'll see is just that there was an attribute `foo` and now there are two attributes `bar1` and `bar2` - but no way of knowing that the first one is just the old attribute.

Comment: Believe it or not that is not a major issue for my usage. The XML documents that I deal with are only used to test the system the ultimately processes them.

If foo -> bar it would be perfectly fine if the program removed foo and created a bar attribute, even if that meant that the value of foo in the original document was lost in the conversion process. 

The idea behind this program is to batch process a bunch of (otherwise manual) conversions. If some data is lost, it is not an issue as it is test data. It would still save a lot of time.

Comment: Essentially, I need the script to do this: add any new required fields (as defined in the schema) to an XML document, and remove or comment out any fields that no longer exist according to the new schema.

If some manual tweeks need to be made to make the data in the XML document compliant with the needs to the system, that's fine. As long as the nontrivial work of adding and removing fields can be done by the script. Let me know what you think of this/if this is possible.

Comment: Yes, this should be possible - still not easy. What you need to do is basically validate those XML files, adding/removing attributes and elements based on the errors found by the validation. The best thing would be to have an existing validation library that is 'pluggable' in some way, so that you can add you own code to handle errors - don't know if such a thing exists though.